# React - call function in child component if parent state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've got an invisible fullscreen event processing component that catches and processes all mouse events. On certain events I want to call a particular function in a child component. I created a state variable in the parent component. I am listening with use effect in the child component if there are some changes to the state variable in the parent component. However the effect hook is being called to often. Is there a better way of doing this? In particular I want to set drawing=true on mouse down and drawing=false on mouse up. If drawing transitions from true to false I want so save something in the database. Therefore it's important that the function in useState is being called only once.

Comment: Maybe your useEffect needs a dependency array? We can't provide you much feedback with no code.

Comment: can you please provide some code, that you've tried, so we can answer you further.

Comment: You could pass to child that state as prop, so in child you could define an useEffect with this prop and call every you need inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have these two possible solutions.

1. If you want useEffect not to be called in the first render, you have to use a custom hook, probably called `useUpdateEffect`. [Here](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useUpdateEffect.md) is a usage guide from react-use package

2. use `useImperativeHandle` to run a function in child from parent.
   example:

```
import React, { forwardRef, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Parent() {
    const ref = useRef<Ref>(null!);

    const handleCallFunction = (): void => ref?.current?.functionInChild();

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleCallFunction}>
                call a function in child from parent
            </button>
            <Child ref={ref} />
        </div>
    );
}

type Ref = {
    functionInChild: () => void;
};

type Props = {};

const Child = forwardRef<Ref, Props>((props, ref) => {
    const functionInChild = () => {
        console.log('called from parent');
    };

    React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ functionInChild }));

    return <div>Child!</div>;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the second option worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put this in your code

```
useEffect(()=>{
   /*Query logic*/
console.log('i fire once');},[your_variable]);
```

**you_variable** which you want to change when this variable changes his value

Comment: Thanks! added it into the child component and it works!